# Is it possible to execute the script at the time of starting the psql container with mounted file?

Tags: docker, cmd, psql

Right now I need 2 command to execute script

1. `docker run -it -v D:/sql:/var/sql governmentpaas/psql psql postgresql://user:123@host:port/db`
2. `\i 'var/sql/script.sql'`

I want to execute with only one command, I mean add second command to first. Something like:
`docker run -it -v D:/sql:/var/sql  governmentpaas/psql /bin/sh -c "psql postgresql://user:123@host:port/db && \i 'var/sql/script.sql'"`

Is it possible to do?

Comment: If you use a `docker run -p` option to publish a port from the database to the host, you can use the `psql` client directly on the host without involving Docker (and needing to quote the command, and needing to bind-mount the data file, and needing administrator-equivalent permissions).

Comment: @DavidMaze good notice. but it's not my case

Answer (score 0):

Working great with -f parameter

```
/bin/sh -c "psql postgresql://user:password@host:port/db -f /var/sql/script.sql"
```